# Do you keep your review's position after removing a build from iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, submit, app-store-connect

Once an app has the state "Waiting for review" in iTunes Connect, if you remove the current build later, and upload a new one directly after, will you keep your position in the review queue of Apple or will it be reset?

From a previous experience, I submitted a build, removed it a week later, re-upload another one 3-4 hours later, and this one was validated several hours after. As if I never removed it but this behaviour would be weird from Apple, isn't it?

Any ideas of iTunes Connect's behaviour about this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually once you exit the review queue, you will have to queue up again for another week. Its uncommon but possible that apple will expedite a review, although apple does not explicitly mention so.

One common scenario is apps containing Apple Watch apps that will be prioritized in the review queue, taking less than a day to pass.

Comment: Do you have any source about all of that or is it just hypothetical? I searched official sources, but nothing more... Anyway, I got the same conclusion, but I was hoping someone will have an official information about it.

Comment: You won't get official sources as its apple's internal process, but based on all the reports people have said, it's basically agreed Woon how the queue works.

Comment: Then you should have right. It's just surprising that sometimes they give you an expedite review just after you remove a build